# Search and replace thousands string in one mysql table from another table

Tags: mysql, replace, confluence

I am trying to update one mysql table which has few columns from which one of the column is having text value (html text). It basically storing content of web page. One row in that table represents one web page. I have about 200K rows in the table, that means 200K web pages data. To be specific, this is Atlassian Confluence application, which is a WIKI and stores pages data in a table called, "bodycontent".

Now I have a situation, where users used to add links of documents from one repository tot he wiki pages. We have just migrated that document repository to another. So whatever links user have added, (which were stored in the bodycontent table) are obsolete now. We have migrated from repository A to repository B. Now I need to update all those links (hyperlinks) which are already there in the bodycontent table. I have got the new hyperlinks in an another mysql table where I have created three columns. Column 1> ID, Column 2>oldlink, Column 3>newlink.

I need to search and replace all the old links from the bodycontent table, wherever it exists in the 200K rows.

For searching and updating few 100links are fine but I have 11K such old links and need to search each of them in bodycontent table and replace with new links.

Please suggest me any efficient solution?

Comment: Can't you just implement a rewrite rule in the web server to redirect all old links to the new ones?

Comment: @drakyoko I cannot, there are few reasons: 1) I am not sure if how apache tomcat will react to 11K rewrite rules, it will be extra overhead on apache tomcat I think (I am not sure though). 2) The application is in java and apache tomcat is bound to run confluence application only, the only way we can configure application is to create plugins, this is something I cannot do right now as the solution needed asap. 3) We have got approval for database update only, I mean policies and all in corporates. :(

Comment: can you help me to write stored procedure which can pick column a from links table and search in bodycontent and replace with column b from links table?

Comment: For performance reasons, I'd first extract all the links from each html column and store that in a table. This way when you write a procedure, you would know which values you need to replace for each row storing different html and there would be no need to check for all links in each row. Having that done you only need to run the replaces for all links that particular html stores

Comment: @SachinKRaj OK, I assumed that those links had a common pattern.

Comment: @ConsiderMe If I understood your suggestion correctly. Let me explain what I have. I have already a table: Three columns: Column 1 = ID, Column 2 = OLD LINK, Column 3 = NEW LINK. I have this list already ready. I need to search OLD link in bodycontent table where a column called body has html content and then replace with NEW LINK. Doing this for every link in 200K rows. That means search replace happens for 11K links in 200K rows. For single replace it takes around 9-10 seconds so if I run 11K search replace it  would be months to run these queries.

Comment: @SachinKRaj this is why I proposed another approach to minimize amount of replaces to only those that are actually needed for each `body` column. Provide some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com/